# 2D array C++ pointer address

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, indexing

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()

    { int arr2D[3][3]; 
    printf("%d\n",((arr2D==*arr2D) && (*arr2D==arr2D[0]))); 
    return o;
    }
```

How the values stores at *arr2D and *arr2d* is same whereas **arr2D** is a constant pointer which will store the address of the *first element* and *arr2D* means the value present at the address which is pointed by arr2D?

Answer (score 2):

If we draw out your array on "paper" it will look like this

```
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| arr2D[0][0] | arr2D[0][1] | arr2D[0][2] | arr2D[1][0] | arr2D[1][1] | arr2D[1][2] | arr2D[2][0] | arr2D[2][1] | arr2D[2][2] |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Then you have to remember that an array naturally decays to a pointer to its first element. That is plain `arr2D` when a pointer is expected, is the same as `&arr2D[0]`.

Now if we "redraw" the array, but only for `arr2D[0]` (which is what is most relevant for your question) with some of the possible pointers:

```
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----+
| arr2D[0][0] | arr2D[0][1] | arr2D[0][2] | ... |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----+
^
|
&arr2D[0]
|
&arr2D[0][0]
```

Since we know that `arr2D` is the same as `&arr2D[0]`, we can then do that substitution in the expression `arr2D == *arr2D`. That gets us `&arr2D[0] == *&arr2D[0]`.

The dereference `*` and address-of `&` operators cancel each other out, so we have `&arr2D[0] == arr2D[0]`.

Now keep up... We know that an array decays to a pointer to its first element, and we know that `arr2D[0]` is an array; That means it will decay to `&arr2D[0][0]`, leaving us with the expression `&arr2D[0] == &arr2D[0][0]`. And as shown those two addresses are the same, which means the comparison will be true.

***Important note:*** While `&arr2D[0]` and `&arr2D[0][0]` might both point to the same location, their *types* are different. The type of `&arr2D[0]` is `int (*)[3]`, while `&arr2D[0][0]` is of type `int *`.

---

Armed with the above information it should be easy to decipher the other comparison `*arr2D == arr2D[0]`, especially since all of the parts of that are already mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

This is not valid C code.

`arr2D` when used in an expression decays to a pointer to the first element, `int (*)[3]`. Whereas `*arr2D` gives the first item of the 2D array, an `int[3]`, which too decays when used in an expression, into an `int*`.

So the code compares an `int (*)[3]` with an `int*`. They are not compatible pointer types and cannot be compared - this is a constraint violation of the standard (C17 6.5.9/2) and the compiler must produce a diagnostic message. Meaning that this is a severe bug, and anyone bothering to try the code in a conforming C compiler would find it.

`*arr2D` and `arr2D[0]` are however always equivalent, per definition of the `[]` operator.

What the code prints is anyone's guess, since code containing constraint violations is to be regarded as having undefined behavior.